# Linux best practice to start and watch another process

Tags: c++, linux, child-process

In my process I need to start/restart another process.
Currently I use a thread with a tiny stack size and the following code:

```
void startAndMonitorA()
{
  while(true)
  {
    system("myProcess");
    LOG("myProcess crashed");
    usleep(1000 * 1000);
  }
}
```

I feel like that's not best practice. I have no idea about the resources the `std::system()` call is blocking or wasting. I'm on an embedded Linux - so in general I try to care about resources.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code as shown would be adequate for most circumstances. If you really care about resource usage, you should be aware that you are starting (and keeping around) a thread for each process you are monitoring. If your program has an event loop anyway, that kind of thing can be avoided at the cost of some additional effort (and an increase in complexity).

Implementing this would entail the following:

- Instead of calling `system()`, use `fork()` and `exec()` to start the external program. Store its PID in a global table.
- Set a `SIGCHLD` handler that notifies the event loop of the exit of a child, e.g. by writing a byte to a pipe monitored by the event loop.
- When a child exits, run `waitpid` with the `WNOHANG` flag in a loop that runs for as long as there are children to reap. `waitpid()` will return the PID of the child that exited, so that you know to remove its PID from the table, and to schedule a timeout that restarts it.

Comment: that means to start the external program somehow and have just one thread monitoring all started programs by catching their `SIGCHLD` and restart them. This will save the resources of having multiple threads and multiple open sh interpreters -- as I understand!?

Comment: @florgeng Yes; if minimizing resources is your goal, spawning a thread per started process is somewhat wasteful. Multiple open `sh` interpreters can be avoided even while still using `system()`, simply prepend `exec` to the command. For example, `system("sleep 10")` will wait for `sh` to finish (which will in turn wait for `sleep` to finish), while `system("exec sleep 10")` will start sh, which will be immediately *replaced* by `sleep`, so the only process you're waiting for is `sleep`.

Answer (score 3):

One problematic piece is restarting immediately: if the child process fails to start that is going to cause 100% CPU usage. It may be a transient error in the child process (e.g. cannot connect to a server). It may be a good idea to add a least one second pause before trying to restart.

---

What `system` call does on Linux is:

1. Sets up signals `SIGINT` and `SIGQUIT` to be ignored.
2. Blocks signal `SIGCHLD`.
3. `fork()`
4. Child process calls `exec()` shell, passing the command line to the shell.
5. Parent process calls `waitpid()` that blocks the thread till the child process terminates.
6. Parent process restores its signal dispositions.

If you were to re-implement the functionality of `system` you would probably omit step 5 (along with steps 1, 2 and 6) to avoid blocking the thread and rely on `SIGCHLD` to get notified when the child process has terminated and needs to be restarted.

In other words, the bare minimum would be to set up a signal handler for `SIGCHLD` and call `fork` and `exec`.

Comment: I added the sleep in between, in my real code I already have it like this, I just tried to keep the example as easy as possible. I think I will stay with the std::system() call for the moment.